# disable date field (only update with datepicker)

Tags: forms, datetime

I am using drupal 6, im my form I put the date field as

```
$form['myform']['from_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',     
    '#title' => t('From date'),       
    '#size' => 8,
    '#default_value' => (arg(5) == null)? '0':arg(5),  
    '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'GetdatePicker(this);'),
);
```

i want that user can not edit this field without using date popup(populated from date picker).
any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 'readonly' => 'readonly' attribute to your field,

ie:

```
$form['myform']['from_date'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',     
'#title' => t('From date'),       
'#size' => 8,
'#default_value' => (arg(5) == null)? '0':arg(5),  
'#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'GetdatePicker(this);', 'readonly' => 'readonly'),
);
```